# Equivalence of two optimization objectives

Tags: convex-optimization

Consider

$$(\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta) = \arg\min_{\beta_0,\beta}\|y-\beta_0 1 - X\beta\|^2$$

and

$$(\tilde\beta_0, \tilde\beta) =\arg\min_{\beta_0,\beta}
= \left\|y- \left( \beta_0 - \frac{1^T X \beta}{n}\right) 1 - X\beta \right\|^2 
$$

Note that $1, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$

Is it true that $\hat\beta_0 = \tilde\beta_0 - \frac{1^T X \tilde\beta}{n}$ and $\hat\beta = \tilde\beta$?

Comment: Is $\ker X$ trivial?

Comment: @copper.hat What is ker X? Kernel of X?

Comment: Yes. I am assuming it is a matrix? Is $1$ in the range of $X$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix. No, 1 is not in the range of $X$.

Comment: Presumably you understand why I am asking these questions?

Comment: @copper.hat Hmm, I think I am not able to connect the dots here. My mind is focused on thinking about this from an optimization perspective rather than linear algebra. What are you trying to get me think about in this situation?